# In Bash, how can I access the date of when a file was last edited?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, command

Basically, I can see that

```
ls -l
```

displays the date that all the files in a directory were last edited. What I want to do is to access the date and then store it into a variable using a .sh script. However, not exactly sure what I can do to do so, and I've looked up the man pages for ls as well as searched up the matter to no avail.

Comment: You want the date directly as it is displayed in `ls -l`?

Comment: It could be any format, actually. I'm just trying to compare the dates of each file against each other, so as long as they are all in the same format, it'd be fine.

Comment: Oh, so we're having an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) it seems…

Comment: Well, when you put it that way, then that's probably the case. I should have more clearly defined my question first.

Comment: You know, you can edit your question and change it to something like: _how can I find all files that have the same ctime as a given file?_ or something similar (if that's what you're trying to do). Also, please specify you linux distribution and version…

Comment: Did you missed this post which have the answer already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212663/filename-last-modification-date-shell-in-script

Comment: @steph I made a [mostly working implementation of `ls`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22839267/3076724) at some point. Should probably help you get the output you're looking for.

Comment: If your still havving problems -- Have you checked my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

If your `date` command supports the `-r` option, you can use it:

```
variable=$(date -r file)
```

The advantage of the `date` command is that you'll be able to format the date in many ways. For example, in seconds since Epoch:

```
variable=$(date -r file +%s)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like my date command supports the -r option; all it seems to support is -u and -a.

Comment: @steph what system are you using?

Comment: I'm using putty on Windows to connect to a Linux server.

Comment: @steph but what linux server is it? what distribution? what version?

Comment: @steph, How come you don't have `-r` option? this is kind a best solution (to my knowledge). At least a +1 from me. Even I came up with same.

Comment: @BroSlow, May be but then that should be tagged accordingly instead we do some speculation. Asking for help without any effort from OP's side. That's just great.

Comment: The speculation is also about what the OP really wants—I'd speculate OP wants to determine files that have same ctime, or something close to that, and in any case nothing related to `ls`/`date`/`stat` whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Use `stat` with the correct format option:

```
stat -c%y file
```

Comment: I seem to get an error when I run the stat command; specifically, I get "stat: Command not found."

Comment: It's located in `/bin/stat` on my machine.