# How to do a loop with filenames in shellscript ordered by 'last modified'?

Tags: shell, unix, imagemagick, ls

i'm new in Linux, and i've been trying to run a script which processes all the files in a folder using ImageMagick's `convert` (I rather do this task in Shell than using `mogrify`, because as far as I know it doesn't save different files). The files have to be processed in 'last modified' order, so I used this code:

```
for file in `ls -1tr {*.jpg,*.png}`; do
    # imagemagick processes with the filename...
done
```

This code breaks for files with spaces, and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11216144/3517253) using `ls` is wrong for these purposes.

I also tried this solution from [this response](http://I%20also%20tried%20this%20solution%20from%20this%20response), but apparently I got it totally wrong (It raised an 'ambiguous redirect' error) and I decided I needed help.

```
while read LINE; do
    ...
done `(ls -1tr {*.png,*.jpg}`
```

So how do I get an ordered list of filenames for a loop? (It doesn't necessarily have to be a FOR...IN loop, it can be a WHILE, or anything.)

Comment: If you want to use `mogrify` without overwriting the input file, you can add `-path outputFolder` into your `mogrify` command and it will write the results in a subdirectory called `outputFolder`, e.g. `mogrify -resize 10% -output results *.jpg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
for file in `ls -1tr {*.jpg,*.png} | awk '{print $9}'`; do
    # imagemagick processes with the filename...
done
```

ls -lrth give's 9 coulmns in output, out of which you need only 9th column(file names), you can get that using awk

If you have space seperated filenames, modify awk print to print all data after 9th column

Comment: I tried this but the `-1tr` flag (for sorting according to the date) returns only the name, then I modified to `awk {print $1}` and it returned only the first name of a space-separated filename as I was afraid.

Comment: If you have space seperated file name you have to modify awk to capture all data after 9th column

Comment: I got the solution by using `{print $0}` for capturing all the arguments in line and then setting the IFS variable as [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2860103/3517253) says, thanks for the help!